# execute if item in an item_frame is in a certain position in minecraft 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to turn on water with a faucet by using a `structure_void` in an invisible `item_frame` in mc1.16

this is my command:

```
/execute if entity @e[x=269,y=66,z=533,type=item_frame,nbt={TileY:269,TileX:66,TileZ:533,ItemId:"minecraft:structure_void",ItemRotation:2}] run say 2
```

I also tried different versions like

```
/execute if entity @e[x=269,y=66,z=533,type=item_frame,nbt={ItemId:"minecraft:structure_void",ItemRotation:2b}] run say 2
```

and many other different versions but it didn't work. Could someone help me please? There is no place for a comparator behind the frame so I have to get NBT data like this!

Comment: Some syntax errors I think:
"nbt={ItemId:"minecraft:structure_void",ItemRotation:2b}"
should probobly be:
"nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:structure_void",ItemRotation:2b}}"        
'ItemRotation' might need to be within 'tag' aswell:
"nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:structure_void",tag:{ItemRotation:2b}}}" aswell as add a 'Count' so:
"nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:structure_void",Count:1b,tag:{ItemRotation:2b}}}"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortuenedly thas wasn't it...

Now my command looks like this: 
/execute if entity @e[x=269,y=66,z=533,type=item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:structure_void",Count:1b,tag:{ItemRotation:2}}}] run say 2


It didn't say error, but it didn't work as well :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you mean to make the player "turn" the structure void.

Because you can test for `item_frame` specifically the only thing needed to be in the `nbt` selector is the `ItemRotation`.

This command will properly execute when the entity in the target location is an item frame with the item rotation as 2:

```
execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,x=269,y=66,z=533,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0,nbt={ItemRotation:2b}]
```

I also used this command to summon the item frame:

```
/summon minecraft:item_frame 269 66 533 {Facing:2b,Invulnerable:1b,Invisible:1b,ItemRotation:1b,Item:
{id:"minecraft:structure_void",Count:1b}}
```

Remember that when the item is rotated the correct way if your using a repeating command block the command will execute 20 times a second until the item is turned again. I would recommend making an off switch with another rotation such as `ItemRotation:6b` that would turn of the water. This way you could test for when the rotation is 2 and this would place a Redstone block next to some other command blocks that would remove the power source to the first command block. and would activate the water as well as activate the command block with the off switch command.

Example command:

```
execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,x=269,y=66,z=533,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0,nbt={ItemRotation:2b}] run setblock x y z redstone_block
```

Then the command block line:

```
activate water
```

Next command block:

```
place Redstone block at the execute command block that tests for the ItemRotation:6b
```

Then remove the Redstone block that the first command block placed, so this can be repeated.

You would need to do this for when it tests for the 2:nd rotation and have another line of command blocks placing a Redstone block next to the command block testing for `ItemRotation:2b`.

The left one has ItemRotation of 0 and the right one has 1. 2, 4, 6 will show the same as 0 as well as 3 5 7 will show the same as 1.
[image: ItemRotation]

Answer (score 1):

It works!!! Thank you so much! Even numbers start the water and odd numbers stop it again, just like i wanted! Great!!!

[image: water-tower]

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed your problem. (^_^)  Also, you can check my answer to mark this question as answered.